# How to update all existing elements in the same level with same parent value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw some words with their shadows using codes like:

```
function myText(g, data)
{
  const update = g.selectAll('g').data(data, d => d.id);

  const enter = update.enter().append('g');

  // bottom element
  enter.append('text')
    .text(d => d.text)
    .attr('fill', 'grey')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => 40 * i + 100)
    .attr('y', 100);

  // top element
  enter.append('text')
    .text(d => d.text)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => 40 * i + 99)
    .attr('y', 99);

  const all = update.merge(enter);

  all.select('text').text(d => d.text);

  const exit = update.exit();

  exit.remove();
}

const g = d3.select( ... ) // some level in scene
  .append('g');

const d1 =
  [
    { id: 1, text: 'a' },
    { id: 2, text: 'b' },
    { id: 3, text: 'c' }
  ];

const d2 =
  [
    { id: 1, text: 'one' },
    { id: 2, text: 'two' },
    { id: 5, text: 'five' }
  ];

myText(g, d1);
myText(g, d2);
```

The logic of `myText` comes from Mike Bostock’s Block [*"General Update Pattern, II"*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221).

Then I got these elements:

```
g
|
|- g
|  |- text 'one'
|  |- text 'a'   <- not updated, expecting 'one'
|
|- g
|  |- text 'two'
|  |- text 'b'   <- not updated, expecting 'two'
|
|- g
   |- text 'five'
   |- text 'five'
```

And I have tried "selectAll in each" etc which also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to update your texts you are actually never updating any data bound to them. Instead, you are updating the data bound to the parent groups, which is working fine, but is never propagated to their already existing child elements.

Propagation of data works while [appending](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append) new elements (emphasis mine):

> Each **new** element inherits the data of the current elements

Data is not inherited by child elements, however, when doing just a simple `.select()` or [`.selectAll()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_selectAll):

> The selected elements do not inherit data from this selection; use selection.data to propagate data to children.

This is what happens when you are trying to set the texts for the update selection, i.e. the selected texts still have the old data bound to them. On the other hand, there is no need to have the same data bound to both the text as well as its shadow text; you could just as well access the parent `<g>`s data for this purpose:

```
all.selectAll('text')
  .text(function() {
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().text;
  });
```

Have a look at this working demo:

```js
function myText(g, data)
{
  const update = g.selectAll('g').data(data, d => d.id);

  const enter = update.enter().append('g');

  // bottom element
  enter.append('text')
//    .text(d => d.text)
    .attr('fill', 'grey')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => 40 * i + 100)
    .attr('y', 100);

  // top element
  enter.append('text')
//    .text(d => d.text)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => 40 * i + 99)
    .attr('y', 99);

  const all = update.merge(enter);

  all.selectAll('text')
    .text(function() {
      return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().text;
    });

  const exit = update.exit();

  exit.remove();
}

const g = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append('g');

const d1 =
  [
    { id: 1, text: 'a' },
    { id: 2, text: 'b' },
    { id: 3, text: 'c' }
  ];

const d2 =
  [
    { id: 1, text: 'one' },
    { id: 2, text: 'two' },
    { id: 5, text: 'five' }
  ];

myText(g, d1);
myText(g, d2);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```